# Is there a point in going to the nether multiple times?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I've gathered 3 lava buckets, and I would like to know if there are any purposes after I got the machine working.

That is, the machine at the end of the tunnel, you dig down until you get iron mine, but if you go sideways you can eventually reach a machine that is broken, and use a lava bucket to fix it. It ends up being a machine where you can convert gold into iron.